# Computer dies (power off) when waking from hibernate, otherwise works fine

Tags: windows-8, boot, laptop, hibernate, thinkpad

I have a strange problem with my Lenovo T520. Since last week, every wake from hibernate has failed right after the Windows 8 logo shows up. The computer simply dies (like I removed the battery, or as if it overheats). When I turn it on again it boots fine, with seemingly no problems or errors. During normal operation I have noticed no issues.

I have had some problems with my discrete GPU, and thought this might be an issue but I've disabled the GPU in bios and it hasn't helped.

To be honest, I don't even know where to begin in terms of troubleshooting: the Windows logs don't register anything abnormal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After some more googling I found solution on the [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/unexpected-shutdown-after-hibernating-or-standby/d9fde351-abbf-46f0-a150-d6f8bfcb065d) website:

1. Run `cmd.exe` as an administrator.
2. Execute command: `bcdedit -enum all`. Look for `Resume from Hibernate` in the output and note the `identifier` part (i.e. `{3d8d3081-33ac-11dc-9a41-806e6f6e6963}`) or copy it to clipboard.
3. Execute command: `bcdedit /deletevalue {identifier} inherit` (`bcdedit /deletevalue {3d8d3081-33ac-11dc-9a41-806e6f6e6963} inherit` in this example).
4. Test hibernation again.

I tried it and it now works. However, I don't know why. My guess is that the hibernation file was corrupted for some reason. Is this the case? Should I be concerned that my hard drive is dying?

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Super User's Q&A format relies on questions being questions and answers being solutions to the question.  There is no mechanism for someone to answer an answer.  You might want to move the question portion of your answer into the question, itself, or make that a new question.